# Can we "complete" model categories to compute derived functors in the usual way?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories, derived-functors

Suppose we have a functor between two model categories $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$. Suppose we don't know that it is a part of a Quillen pair. Nevertheless, it can still happen that the derived functor $\mathbb{L}F\colon \mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{C})\to \mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{D})$ exists. Then we apriori don't know that it can be computed by the formula $$\mathbb{L}F(A)=\gamma F(R)\phantom{aaaa}(*)$$ for some cofibrant replacement $R\to A$ of $A$ (here $\gamma$ denotes the localization funtor).

> Can we somehow extend (or maybe we should say "complete") the categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ to $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ and $\hat{\mathcal{D}}$, and extend the functor $F$ to $\hat{F}$ so that there will exist $\mathbb{L}\hat{F}$ which will restrict to $\mathbb{L}F$, and such that $\hat{F}$ can be computed by the formula $(*)$?

It feels like there should exist something analogous to the case of abelian categories. There, if we don't have enough resolutions, we can always complete our categories and extend the functor in the desired way (like extending category of coherent sheaves to quasi-coherent sheaves in order to have injective resolutions).

> Or maybe we can extend $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D},F$ in such a way that $\hat{F}$ becomes a part of a Quillen pair? Is there any result like that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you assuming at least that $F$ has a right adjoint $G$?

Comment: @DavidWhite No, I don't think so... At least for the first question. For the second question I guess we need to assume something about $F$. For example, it should commute with colimits or limits (if we want it to be left or right Quillen). Maybe we can assume it already has an adjoint if it is necessary.

Comment: Adding new resolutions seems like a terrible idea. As far as I know, the only reason why model structures do actually compute the classical derived functors of homological algebra is because there are enough resolutions already.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am not asking for *minimal* such extensions. Maybe one can embed the model categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ into something much bigger...

Comment: Well, one can [embed model categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6659) satisfying certain smallness conditions into combinatorial model categories, but this procedure can't really be used to turn an arbitrary functor into a left Quillen functor. At minimum the original functor must preserve finite colimits, cofibrations, and trivial cofibrations.

Comment: Anyway, let me describe a situation where a derived functor exists by accident. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be any model category. Then $\mathrm{Hom} : \mathcal{M}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{M} \to \mathbf{Set}$ has a right derived functor, where we consider $\mathbf{Set}$ with the discrete model structure, namely $\mathrm{Hom} : \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{M}^\mathrm{op} \times \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{M} \to \mathbf{Set}$. It seems very doubtful to me to say that there should be a way to see this in "the usual way" by extending $\mathcal{M}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Could you explain with more details what you mean by "analogous to the case of abelian categories" please ? The only thing I can say is that taking a cofibrant (fibrant resp.) replacement in a model category is a little bit like taking a projective (injective resp.) resolution in an abelian category, but in a non-additive setting. But I guess that you already know that.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher Yes, you are right. In fact, if we cansider model category of complexes over an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ (with enough projectives) then taking cofibrant replacements of objects in $\mathcal{A}\subset Com(\mathcal{A})$ is exactly taking projective resolutions. What I was asking is, in abelian categories we can't sometimes compute a derived functor by simply applying the functor to the resolution. Then, we extend our categories so that we can compute the derived functor in the usual way (by applying it to a resolution). I was asking if this is a case in model categories.

Comment: More precisely, the axiomatics itself makes the cofibrant resolutions to exist always, in any model category. But it is still not clear to me, why can we compute the derived functor by applying it to a cofibrant replacement, unless it is not a part of a Quillen pair. So I was interested, maybe we can extend the categories and the functor so that it will become Quillen, and so we know we can compute the derived functor by applying it to a resolution.